# JSON fetch URL content for Android

Tags: android, json

Friends,
  I have a problem in parsing the json content directly from url given http://samplejson.com/transactions.json, but when i store the same url content as a text file in my res/raw folder it parse the data as well,but when fetching the url content from net it shows an exception (i.e)
**A JSONArray text must starts with '[' at character 1 of...**

what's the wrong here.help me to fix this problem

---

```
URL url_net = new URL("http://samplejson.com/transactions.json"); 
InputStream is = url_net.openStream(); 
byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()]; 
while (is.read(buffer) != -1); 
String jsontext = new String(buffer); 
JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext); 
x = "JSON parsed.\nThere are [" + entries.length() + "]\n\n"; 
int i; 
for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++) { }
```

Comment: OK, post the code you have to get the text from HTTP and load the JSON. I looked at the JSON itself, it was fine.

Comment: URL url_net = new URL("http://184.106.227.45/quaddeals/university-of-illinois/androids/transactions/type:available/752/transactions.json");

      InputStream is = url_net.openStream();
      byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
      while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
      String jsontext = new String(buffer);
      JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
      
      x = "JSON parsed.\nThere are [" + entries.length() + "]\n\n";
     
      int i;
      for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++)
      { } these the code i'm trying to fetch data fron url and to store in string buffer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, your code seems to be reading all the HTTP including the headers. That is why yours does not start with "[".

Here is the code that I use to get back the string content of an HTTP GET:

```
public static String getStringContent(String uri) throws Exception {

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(uri));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while(true )
        {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                break;
            sb.append(s);

        }
        buf.close();
        ips.close();
        return sb.toString();

        } 
    finally {
               // any cleanup code...
            }
        }
```

Comment: Notice the response.`getEntity()`.getContent() which refers to HTTP payload.

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to use `String content = client.execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler())`, a saving of a dozen lines :)

Comment: Thanks Dave. Was not aware of BasicResponseHandler().