# Check if webview can reach the server

Tags: android, connection

Is it possible to check if Android WebView can reach the server or not? So if it can't reach the server or a specific website it returns something like false or so? I've searched quite a lot and some people said you can use OnReceivedError() but that doesn't work for some reason... So how can I check if the app can reach the given server (host address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2001824/446576

Don't rely on webview errors, check connectivity instead.

To test a specific remote host, try to download a page with `HttpClient` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4724491/446576)

Comment: But with that code it won't check if it really has internet connection right? So when wifi is on and connected to a network but the network doesn't have access it doesn't give an error... So it's not totally correct?

Comment: With first link, you don't get error, you get a boolean: is there someway to access internet? With second link you can trully test connectivity. You can set timeout too.

Comment: Thank you!! I wIll figure it out.